# Array displaying repeated object in table view cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I am having a NSArray of size 11 as it formed below.

`labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"DIN #",@"Brand Name",@"Full Name",
                   @"Strength", 
                   @"Medication Type",
                   @"Presciption ID",
                   @"Next Dosage",
                   @"Required Dosage",
                   @"ada",
                   @"dasdada",
                   @"dasdasad",
                   nil];`

but when i am displaying this array in tableview cell Using this code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dueueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   
UILabel* nameLabel = nil;

if(cell == nil) {   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 10.0, 160.0, 44.0 )];

    nameLabel.text =[labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 


    nameLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    nameLabel.numberOfLines =0;
    [nameLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize expectedlabelsize = [nameLabel.text sizeWithFont:nameLabel.font constrainedToSize:nameLabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGRect newFrame =nameLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height =expectedlabelsize.height;


   [cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];

return cell;}
```

O/P is as below .

DIN

Brand Name

Full Name

Strength

Medication Type

Presciption ID

Next Dosage

Required Dosage

**DIN**

**Brand Name**

**Full Name**

**see after required Dosage again DIN,Brand Name,Full Name showing ,which are already shown**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `viewWithTag` method and i have used it following method. Try like this. I think it will be helpful to you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    UILabel* nameLabel = nil;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        [titleLbl removeFromSuperview];
    }
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 7.0, 10.0, 160.0, 44.0 )];
    nameLabel.text = [labels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    nameLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    nameLabel.tag =1;
    nameLabel.numberOfLines =0;
    [nameLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize expectedlabelsize = [nameLabel.text sizeWithFont:nameLabel.font constrainedToSize:nameLabel.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGRect newFrame =nameLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height =expectedlabelsize.height;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: nameLabel];
    return cell;
}
```