# Selecting cells and moving them to a separate array?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, nsmutablearray

I have the following code in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, and I want the user to be able to tap on a cell, have the cell show the checkmark, and add the selected cells to a separate array. I also would like the user to be able to tap an already selected cell, which will then take away the checkmark and remove it from the array.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.setupTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    SetupCell *cell = (SetupCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Feed name: %@", cell.setupFeedName.text);

    if ([self.selectedCells containsObject:cell.setupFeedName.text]) {
        [self.selectedCells removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [self.selectedCells addObject:cell.setupFeedName.text];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [self.setupTable reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%i cells are selected.", [self.selectedCells count]);
    NSLog(@"%i cells are not selected.", [self.setupFeeds count]);

}
```

The NSLog outputs the following:

```
2013-08-12 07:04:58.767 [13921:c07] Feed name: Politico
2013-08-12 07:04:58.768 [13921:c07] 0 cells are selected.
2013-08-12 07:04:58.769 [13921:c07] 6 cells are not selected.
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is what Console shows:

```
2013-08-12 07:31:40.390[14117:c07] Feed name: Huffington Post
2013-08-12 07:31:40.392[14117:c07] 5 cells are selected.
2013-08-12 07:31:40.392[14117:c07] 6 cells are not selected.
```

Here is the code:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.setupTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    SetupCell *cell = (SetupCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Feed name: %@", cell.setupFeedName.text);

    if ([[self.selectedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:cell.setupFeedName.text]) {
        [self.selectedCells removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        [self.selectedCells addObject:cell.setupFeedName.text];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    NSLog(@"%i cells are selected.", [self.selectedCells count]);
    NSLog(@"%i cells are not selected.", [self.setupFeeds count]);

    [self.setupTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Try this NSLog before reload. and what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Then what happening in your case?

Comment: are you initialising the self.selectedCells? if yes then where?

Comment: @HinataHyuga Let me try that now.

Comment: @Ashwin, sorry for not being clear. The current code will select the cell and show the checkmark, but will not deselect and remove checkmark.

Comment: @HinataHyuga It shows the same output.

Comment: @iPhoneNerd Okay, thank you for that. The output now shows some data. However, on launch, when I tap a cell, it doesn't show the checkmark, and seems to be adding to the array and not removing them properly. Check my updated question.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750753/uitableviewcell-accessory-type-checked-on-tap-set-other-unchecked

Comment: selectedCells =[[NSMUtableArray alloc]init]; //Have u used this line in code ???

Comment: @h.kishan yes, in my viewdidload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array which stores the selected cells. And keep the track of selected cells. If cell is tapped again then remove that particular cell from array.

Take detailed information from 
[example given](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/19/multiplecheck-in-table-uitableview/)

Comment: Umm... this is what I am trying to do. Please look closer at my code. I am trying to add the selected cells to a separate array.

Comment: checkout the example link, you will get your solution

Comment: Okay this worked! But how can I print how many selected cells and how many non-selected cells there are into the Console?

Comment: you will get it from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

I did that in way below, but i took the custom buttons on cell to check uncheck.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

 UITableViewCell * cell = 
 [tableHistory dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {

 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
 }

 else
 {

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
 }

 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(270.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];

if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"check"])

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-with-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 else
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [button addTarget:self   action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:button];


 cell.textLabel.text = [cellDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arrayTktcode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

[cell addSubview:btnUnScan];

[cell addSubview:btnUScan];

return cell;

}

-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableHistory];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableHistory indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
{
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-with-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"check"];
 }
 else
{
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];
}
}
```

check [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814060/check-uncheck-buttons-in-uitableviews-cell).

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you want i still doesn't got your requirement properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
   // use this in didSelectRow
    NSUInteger index = [self.selectedCells indexOfObject:cell.setupFeedName.text];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
       [self.selectedCells removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else

    {
     [self.selectedCells addObject:cell.setupFeedName.text];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
```