# CheckBox in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In UITableView, I want to put check uncheck buttons,when I click on first row[indexpath.row=0] remaining rows will uncheck and when click on indexpath.row>0 then row=0 unchceck. I have to do  viceversa  ,

intially I took an array with all objects uncheck and when check it that index will replace object check,

```
for(int i=0; i<[carwasharray count]; i++)
{
    [arrayCheckUnchek addObject:@"Uncheck"];
}
/cell row at indexpath my code is
cell.textLabel.text = [carwasharray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row==0) {
     button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.tag=1;
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
}
else{
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, 7.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    button.tag=2;
if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)buttonClic:(id)sender
{
//Getting the indexPath of cell of clicked button
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:carwashtable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [carwashtable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if (button1.tag==1)
{
    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {

     //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       // [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];
        button.tag=3;
        [self buttonClicked:button];
    }
    else
    {
        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];

        button.tag=3;
        [self buttonClicked:button];

    }
}
else if(button1.tag==0){
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

}

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{ 
//Getting the indexPath of cell of clicked button
 CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:carwashtable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [carwashtable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
// No need to use tag sender will keep the reference of clicked button
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if (button.tag==2) {
    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {      
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];

        button1.tag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];

    }
}
else
{
    if ([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Check"]) {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

now its working only 1st time when I click row=1, the row=0 wil uncheck, upto this ok, but when I recheck row=0 it will also check..

thank in advance

Comment: Just I am curious to know.. Why you are using checkbox? Can't you use toggle button?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814060/check-uncheck-buttons-in-uitableviews-cell

Comment: you want to select only one check?

Comment: i will use check and an uncheck values in further class.. @achievelimitless

Comment: NO,now i have 5 rows, when i check row=0 remaining rows to uncheck. vice versa

Comment: You can do the same by [YourSwitch isOn].

Comment: Clarify me you want to select only one checkbox?

Comment: Do you want something like select all feature? means clicking on 1st will make all selected and unselcting that will unselect all. If all other then 1st selected then 1st must be automatically selected and any one gets unselected then 1st will be automatically unselected?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use checkmarks and not `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` ? It helps you to avoid using extra elements in the cell.

Comment: when i check row zero remaining four uncheck and check any remaining four only row zero to uncheck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks every one who given me a reply.... I got the answer it working fine now

same code but slightly changes...

```
//cell for row at indexpath....
  if (indexPath.row==0) {

    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(completebuttonClic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     button1.tag=1;
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(240.0, 7.0,25.0, 25.0)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
}
else{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(240.0, 7.0, 25.0, 25.0)];
    button.tag=2;
    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_ico.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
return cell;
```

}

```
//calling button targets

-(void)completebuttonClic:(id)sender
{
//completebutton clicked
//Getting the indexPath of cell of clicked button
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:carwashtable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [carwashtable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if (button1.tag==1)
{
    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {

        button.tag=3;
        button1.tag=0;
        [self buttonClicked:button];
    }
    else
    {

        button.tag=3;
        [self buttonClicked:button];

    }
}
else if(button1.tag==0){
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_ico.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [selectrows removeObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",selectrows);
```

}

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
//Getting the indexPath of cell of clicked button
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero tablviewname];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableviewname indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
// No need to use tag sender will keep the reference of clicked button
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
if (button.tag==2) {
    if([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
    {       NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_ico.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      if (button1.imageView.image==[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_ico.png"]) {
  //adding selected rows in a selectrows array
            [selectrows removeObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];
        [selectrows addObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        button1.tag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_ico.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];
        [selectrows removeObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i=1; i<[carwasharray count]; i++) {
        if ([[arrayCheckUnchek objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Check"]) {
            [arrayCheckUnchek replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"Uncheck"];
            [carwashtable reloadData];
            [selectrows removeObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:i]];
        }}
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selectrows addObject:[carwashtypeid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",selectrows);
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView merely displays the UITableViewCell(s) you want it to.

I would recommend creating a Prototype cell that will hold your text and "CheckBox"

Here is a page that demonstrates a few different approaches to creating custom UITableViewCell objects.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Understanding how a task can be accomplished is as important as accomplishing the task itself.

Answer (score 0):

Having an array with string value is not very efficient way to know that current cell checked or unchecked status i would recommend you to create and custom cell and use a custom button class for check button like https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSCheckBoxView so you can ask from cell what is the status

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

I would keep all selected cell's indices in an `NSMutableArray`, say selectedCellsArray.

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I would first check if the selected cell is at index 0 using `indexPath.row`. If it is cell 0, I would do this:

```
[selectedCellsArray removeAllObjects];
[selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

If the selected cell's index is not 0, I would check if the selectedCellsArray contains 0, and remove it using:

```
if([selectedCellsArray containObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]])
    [selectedCellsArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

And add the selected cell's index with:

```
[selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
```

So the final code becomes:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){

    [selectedCellsArray removeAllObjects];
    [selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

}else{

    if([selectedCellsArray containObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]])
        [selectedCellsArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

    [selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

}

[yourTableView reloadData];
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I would check if the selectedCellsArray contains the current cell. If it does, change it's accessory type with :

```
if ([selectedCellsArray containObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
   [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
else
   [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

The advantage here is that you can use the selectedCellsArray to process the information further.

Comment: Rename `selectedCellsArray` to `checkUncheckArray` and place the code in the respective methods I have mentioned. Comment out the code where you add the `UIButton` in your cell, and run your project. It should give you what you are looking for, except, you do not need to add `NSString`s i your array, just `NSNumbers`. If you want, I will edit the post to give you full method implementations for the functionality you are looking for, without any `UIButtons`, target methods, etc